# using VersionControl_Git pear package fails

Tags: php, git, pear

I am trying to deploy by cloning my git project on my webserver, but i cannot get it to work

```
<?    
require_once 'VersionControl/Git.php';

$git = new VersionControl_Git('/home/xxx/public_html/yyy');

$git->createClone('http://github.com/maysam/braincheck.git');

?>
```

but I get an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught   **VersionControl_Git_Exception**: Some errors in executing git command Output: Error: error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing http://www.github.com/maysam/braincheck.git/info/refs fatal: HTTP request failed in **/home/xxxx/php/VersionControl/Git.php** on line **164** Exception trace #FunctionLocation 0VersionControl_Git_Util_Command->execute()/home/xxxx/php/VersionControl/Git.php:164 1VersionControl_Git- in /home/xxxx/php/VersionControl/Git/Util/Command.php on line 237

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a `git://` URL.

```
$git->createClone('git://github.com/maysam/braincheck.git');
```

Comment: Some errors in executing git command Output: Error: github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Connection refused fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection refused) in <b>/home/whampoa/php/VersionControl/Git.php</b> on line <b>164</b>